# When selecting today's date using datepicker always saves and defaults to 1899-12-30

Tags: vb6, datepicker

This is an environment issue, but I'm not sure what to look for. Basically when the user tries to select today's date using Sheridan's datepicker it either leaves it blank or when trying to save the record saves it as 12/30/1899. It's an application using vb6 and sybase 9. Every other date works correctly but today's date.

Also, I observed that today's date box always remains selected no matter what. Could anyone give me suggestions on steps or things I can check to get to the reason why this maybe happening. Re-registered the ocx files, tried attaching debugger and reinstalling software. Nothing worked, would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: If you have other controls of the same type that are working the way you expect them to work I would guess that the code is setting the value some place, or there are 1 or more properties of the control that are set incorrectly.

Comment: @jac Well, the problem is I have not seen this problem with other systems running the same version of our software. And, I can't really make a code change as it's a pretty old version and this is not a known thing. I feel it's something to do with somewhere the current date function is failing.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the impression this was running correctly on other machines. The only other thing I can think of are the regional settings on the affected machine.

Comment: @jac no problems, thanks for your suggestions. I haven't tried myself changing the regional settings, do you mean the time zone? I believe they did try to change their time zone from Eastern to Central. If I may ask how can that lead to this problem?

Comment: I mean the date formats or the language.

Comment: @jac no luck changing the date formats or language. Any other suggestions?

Comment: What is Sheridan's datepicker?

Comment: @IlyaKurnosov it's a third party plugin we use. http://sheridan-data-widgets.software.informer.com/

Comment: It's actually specifically the calendar widget - Find more info here http://www.componentsource.com/products/calendar-widgets/summary.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that they had wrong actually a further version of that ocx somehow on their machine. When I put the correct older one and re-registered it, **worked** as it should.

Also, although maybe not in this case. But, I found problem could be cause as suggested in comments by corrupt/odd regional date format settings. In addition you should also rebuild all user profiles once you change those settings. And, we did those things before fixing it using the above. In any case, thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

My gut is telling me that this isn't related to your environment, but more a bug in the plugin itself. Given that Sheridan's datepicker is a proprietary plugin it appears you really only have a couple of options:

1. Contact the developer and issue a bug fix request via the **Suggest a correction** link on this page: http://data-widgets.software.informer.com/
2. Modify your code so that if the date is empty or 12/30/1899 you **default to today's date**

If I were you, I would be doing number 2 as an interim measure while waiting for a response from number 1.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit hackish, but I've implemented these kind of solutions before: Have you tried to write a small app to do API hooking on that application (since you don't have the source code) and hook on the function (either in the app or Windows itself (by using detours maybe?)) which gets the date and act accordingly?

Also, I'd use this contact method instead -> http://www.componentsource.com/services/about-us/contact.html because the software.informer thing is some kind of page like softonic and I'm kinda sure you won't get as much attention as to a fix from the developer itself.

Sorry for answering here though, I don't have enough reputation to make comments yet :P