# jQuery datetimepicker input text showing date 31/12/1899 when time selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the jquery datetimepicker and set it up as follows

```
$('.fddatetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
        });
```

No date is set by default. When I increment either of the hour or minute sliders for the first time by one place, I get the correct time but the date is set to 31/12/1899 in the input textbox. When i move the slider again it changes to the current date which is what I want.

Does anyone know why the initial increment of the slider causes the date to be 31/12/1899?

I also see this behaviour if i click anywhere on the slider for the first time and then the correct date is displayed when I click on the sliders any further times.

Comment: Might be this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964112/when-selecting-todays-date-using-datepicker-always-saves-and-defaults-to-1899-1

Comment: Have used some jQuery to ensure any 1899 date is replaced with current date

Answer (score 4):

just change the format of datetimepicker by using the below code. It will work like a charm.
I had the same issue and I fixed using that approach below code.

```js
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
                format: "dd-mm-yyyy hh:ii:00P",
                autoclose: true
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "startDate: new Date" property to start on the current date.

Example:

```
$('.fddatetimepicker').datetimepicker({ 
             dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
             startDate: new Date
        });
```

More options and properties in:
http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Answer (score -1):

Try using format: 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:ii:ss P'
The trick is to make sure your date format is the same as what the back-end returns.